# Messengers don't show incoming call when they are not active

Tags: internet, viber-messenger, telegram

Samsung A10 with Android 11. Nor Viber, nor Telegram shows incoming call when they are not active. I mean, that if the messenger is open (in memory) and it is currently being used (focused) then incoming call is shown. However, if another application is used (but messenger is still open) then incoming call is not shown.

I think, the problem is that when messenger is not active it loses internet connection, because when Telegram becomes active (user switched to Telegram) it shows in the title "Connecting". Viber also shows something similar.

This is my mother's phone. It worked well before, but something happened. Either she changed some settings or the problem in updates.

Could anyone help to fix this problem?

Comment: Samsung devices are known for their aggressive battery saving. My guess is that you are "victim" of the problem this site is dedicated to: https://dontkillmyapp.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix it. Settings > Apps > (⁝) menu > Special Access. Here you will find something like `Data usage with traffic economy` (my translation). Find your application and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happened to me as well. However, it wasn't with Messenger, but with another app. Go to settings>apps and find the messenger. Then click the app and go to Notifications and turn on Allow notifications. Here you will find call notifications also then turn on also.